# iOS Undefined symbol: Alamofire Xcode 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

Getting these 2 errors while using Alamofire 5.6.2 as a dependency in my Cocoapod

Xcode Version 13.4.1
Cocoapod Version 1.11.3
Alamofire Version 5.6.2

Undefined symbol: Alamofire.AF.getter : Alamofire.Session

Undefined symbol: dispatch thunk of Alamofire.Session.request(_: Alamofire.URLConvertible, method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameters: [Swift.String : Any]?, encoding: Alamofire.ParameterEncoding, headers: Alamofire.HTTPHeaders?, interceptor: Alamofire.RequestInterceptor?, requestModifier: ((inout Foundation.URLRequest) throws -> ())?) -> Alamofire.DataRequest

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error:
go target *AppTest* and *AppUITest*

```
Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries
```

add the linked library "Alamofire".

[image]